# TextInputLayout not showing HTML styled text

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I have a few TextInputLayouts that are used in a fragment. Now, for the hint for some of them, I need to display either subscript or superscript (ex. g<sub>n</sub> or s<sup>2</sup>). When I use these tags in my string resource, they aren't displayed. My resource looks like this:

```
<string name="some_string">meters<sup>2</sup></string>
```

In regards to the TextInputLayout, I've tried setting the hint in XML and programatically, with no success, like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_example"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:hint="@string/some_string"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and

```
TextInputLayout mTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_example);
mTextInputLayout.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.some_string)));
```

Now, I know that in the developer guide it only mentions that `<b>, <i>, and <u>` are supported, but looking at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/core/java/android/content/res/StringBlock.java#L166 you can see that quite a few more tags are supported.

Having said that, it seems that no tag is working. For example, if I use the `<i>` tag, the text is not italicized. Also, I've tried using the same string resource on just a plain TextView, and it doesn't work there either. At first, I thought that it was just an M-DP2 issue, so I tried it in a KitKat emulator, and it's not working there either.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

I had sort a similar problem. I fixed it by doing the `<sup>` when setting the text instead of in the xml.

```
.setText(Html.fromHtml(mContext.getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING) + 
"<sup><small>2</small></sup>"));
```

Comment: That works just fine on a TextView and a plain EditText. However, it doesn't work on an EditText wrapped in a TextInputLayout. Hmmmm, I wonder if it's a bug with the TextInputLayout....
Thanks for your suggestion. It helped me narrow the problem down quite a bit.